# Using functions of items in jQuery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'n using knockout js and jQuery templates. So i want to render some model with name and date. Problem is in Date field. I've wrote function that print date in my language natural form, and want to use it in template.

I've wrote this template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template">
    ${Name} (${Date().toRussianDateString()})
</script>
```

but recived error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

So i've found this solution:

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template">
    ${Name} (${$data.Date().toRussianDateString()})
</script>
```

of using $data and $item variables. Is right solution? Can i wrote this template without using $date and $item?

Thanx.

Comment: is the solution working for you?

Comment: this solution works well, but it seems to be "bad smeeling" for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little dirty because you're mixing the dead-in-the-water jquery.tmpl engine with native KO templates.

If you're able to use the latest version of KO, you can just write this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    $data.Name ($data.Date().toRussianDateString())
</div>
```

Notice that is inline; you don't need any separate script block or named templates.

Comment: why I can't find it at KO site? This code looks very nice and clean. Thx!

Comment: The latest version of KO was officially released just the other day. Check it out here: KO 2.0: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/